# Memory Leak when changing views in SpriteKit (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game in iOS with SpriteKit. Basic set up is that there is a storyboard with several view controllers, one of them being the GameViewController. When I switch from the GameScene to another view (after hte level is completed) it calls the GameScene deinit(), but the memory does not drop. Therefore after every level screen is initiated, the memory usage creeps up.

I've checked for retain cycles and could not find any, but that's not saying much I guess since I'm pretty new to this. Also the fact that deinit is being called from the GameScene after transferring views indicates that the GameScene is being dismissed.

Here is a summary of my code

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    weak var gsDel: GameSceneDelegate?
    var player = Player()
    func checkEndLevel() {
        self.removeAllChildren()
        self.removeAllActions()
        gsDel!.player = player
        gsDel!.levelEnded()
   }
}
```

and in my GameViewController...

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GameSceneDelegate {
    weak var scene:GameScene? = GameScene()
    var player: Player?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
    }
    func levelEnded() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
        let levelVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LevelViewController") as! LevelViewController
        levelVC.player = player!
        self.view?.window?.rootViewController = levelVC
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {### Try calling deinit here####})`

Comment: As in `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {self.scene = GameScene()}` ?

Comment: no `completion: { deinit { /* do something */ } }`

Comment: It may have to be `self.deinit`